# How to show labels exactly around a circle in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, thematic-map

I found an interesting way of proportional symbol mapping and labeling, I think this was made by Adobe Illustrator but I couldn't find out if it can be done in QGIS. What I am interested in the most is the way how text (attributes) appear around circles. I literally have no idea of how to make such thematic map labeling like this in QGIS.

This is the picture:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In brief**

You should split each circle in 2 halves, then convert them to polyline (or any mean to mimic the top and bottom halves perimeters). The main thing is to have at the end a layer with the top perimeter and the bottom perimeter.

Then you label the top one with a curve labeling with a top setting and label the bottom one with a bottom labeling.

**Below the How-to-do with screen shots**

The table of your entities should look like this (it's a test example, it's going to be different with your data). I created a position field and a label field here.

[image: Table]

In the case where you keep one physical layer, you duplicate your layer and set the filter to match 'UP' for a copy of the layer and  'DOWN' for the other (tip : when somebody will have set this property in the data defined field this will be simpler)

[image: Filter]

It should look like this in the properties :

[image: properties query builder]

For each, you set up different labeling properties

Below layer

[image: Below]

Upper layer

[image: Upper]

then you get :

[image: Curvy]

Comment: Well now I feel silly...

Comment: Don't be, we are all learning everyday  That's what Stack Exchange is all about !

Comment: I really love your solution but I'm struggling with splitting circles in two halves. At first, I had a point layer. I created buffers around them, so I gained polygons that I converted to polylines. My problem is that I cannot cut them horizontally in half. Not even the "Poligon Splitter" plugin does what I want. Could you please help me how did you do that?

Comment: For this example, i just created a basic circle that i manually split in two. However, for a big number of circle, i suppose you might need to create  some horizontal lines that spread horizontally across the circle limits. From the circle middle, you need to create two point, one with (X + circle radius, Y) one with (X - radius circle, Y) then create a line between those two. Then you splt the circle line layer by the horizontal line layer... Or you can just manually use the split feature tool in the advanced editing toolbar manually. I'll have a look in case i missed something.

Comment: I'll try this as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a built-in way or a plugin to make labels conform to a curve (or to any shape other than a straight line). The only way I can think of to achieve this effect in QGIS is to use an HTML frame for each label in the print composer. HTML is not my strong suit, but I found a few sites that explain how to do this (links at bottom of this post). It sounds pretty tedious - probably much easier to produce a map without labels, then add them in a different program. Or produce the labels in another program, save as images, and add the images into the print composer.

https://css-tricks.com/set-text-on-a-circle/ 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990284/curved-text-using-html-css 
https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/1250.htm